Infinite output command freezing the GUI
Trying to run a command like:
"Python.exe" with argument "c:\file.py" that contain the script :
i=0
while i>=0:
    print(i)
    i=i+1

this should give an infinite output, but instead, all the Application freeze and i can't stop the process !!
How to synchronise output without freezing gui ?

Slow it down with something like time.sleep(1) in the loop.

You might be facing this issue because the infinite loop is preventing other processes from running. To prevent the program's interface from freezing, try running the loop in a separate thread to keep it responsive.
If the code is causing freezes on another system, it could be due to resource limitations. Adding a small delay with time.sleep() might help resolve this.
import threading
import time

stop_event = threading.Event()

def run_script():
    i = 0
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        print(i)
        i += 1
        time.sleep(0.1)  # adjust the delay to control output speed

# create and start the thread
script_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_script)
script_thread.start()

# stopping the thread after 5 seconds
time.sleep(5)
stop_event.set()

